# CSS styles do not apply correctly on deployed Sinatra app on fly.io

Tags: css, ruby, deployment, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that is minimally styled using Bootstrap and CSS.

Here is a snippet of the head section with the two CSS links

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Best Buy App | <%= @title %> </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500"
          rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

When I run the server locally, here is how it appears

[image: correct image]

However the deployed version at the [live link](https://best-buy.fly.dev/) displays like the image below

[image: Incorrect image]

When I deploy, it succeeds without any error. When I run the `fly logs`, I can't see any error. What could be causing that difference and causing the CSS not to load correctly?

Comment: When I click on the "live link" it looks exactly as you desire.

Comment: you're probably looking at cached `/stylesheets/styles.css`

Comment: Thanks Alex, it turns out that was the issue. After doing a hard refresh `Ctrl, Shift and the 'R' key` the live link now looks as I expect it.

Upon digging further I  noticed in the browser’s network monitor that /stylesheets/styles.css and the images have an HTTP response header “last-modified: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:01 GMT”, which might be causing the caching issues.

I will look into that see what's going on.